# how to use async.retry within async.race function

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I'm using async.race function in nodejs to call 10 functions in parallel, now some of the calls fail and I want to give them a retry, for that I want to use async.retry function.

Here is my code snippet:

```
async.retry({
    interval: 0,
    times: 5,
    }, this.racemethod, function callback(err, result) {
    // do something with the result
    });

public async racemethod() {
  async.race([
    async function f1(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("Q.txt");
    },
    async function f2(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("R.txt");
    },
    async function f3(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("S.txt");
    },
    async function f4(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("T.txt");
    },
    async function f5(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("U.txt");
    },
    async function f6(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("V.txt");
    },
    async function f7(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("W.txt");
    },
    async function f8(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("X.txt");
    },
    async function f9(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("Y.txt");
    },
    async function f10(callback) {
      await agent.TEST("Z.txt");
    },
],
// main callback
function callback(err, result) {
    // the result will be equal to 'two' as it finishes earlier
});
```

}

Here is documentation of async.race function: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#race

Here is documentation of async.retry function:
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#retry

I'm new to this, so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: so, you're using `async library`, with `promises` (wrapped in `async/await`) ... not only does that make the code look confusing, but also, all the `f1` ... `f10` don't bother calling the callback - so ... the async library isn't being used properly ... here's one thing to avoid ... `async library` **mixed with** `promises` - regardless if  they wrapped in `async` (the ES2015+ keyword)/`await` or not

Comment: Agree @JaromandaX, what are your suggestions to this, I might not be using the library correctly, please see my updated code snippet as well.

Comment: as I said ... `Promise`s and `async library`  don't play well with each other

Comment: Don't use async.js when you use promises.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: code in answer is for javascript, not typescript - as the code in the question, apart from the `public` qualifier for `racemethod`, looks like javascript not typescript

Here's how you'd do it **without** the async library - the reason you'd want to do it without the async library is because it's quite hard to write code that mixes the async library and promises without breaking something!

Note: you also don't need the `async`/`await` ES2016+ keywords, at least, not as often as you use them

And, just to be clear, `async library` methods like `async.race`, `async.retry` - have nothing at all to do with the ES2016+ `async/await` syntax sugar for `Promise`s

With one of these generic "retry" functions

```
const retry = fn => () => fn().catch(() => retry(fn));

const limitedRetry = (cont, fn) => fn().catch(err => cont > 0 ? limitedRetry(cont - 1, fn) : Promise.reject(err));

const wait = (time, result) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time, result));
const limitedRetryDelay = (cont, delay, fn) => fn().catch(err => cont > 0 ? wait(delay).then(() => limitedRetryDelay(cont - 1, delay, fn)) : Promise.reject(err));
```

Your code becomes (unlimited retries - not recommended)

```
let winner = Promise.race([
    retry(() => agent.TEST("Q.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("R.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("S.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("T.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("U.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("V.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("W.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("X.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("Y.txt")),
    retry(() => agent.TEST("Z.txt"))
]);
```

or- to limit the number of retries (to 10)

```
    limitedRetry(10, () => agent.TEST("Q.txt")),
    ... etc
```

or - to limit the number of retries to 10, with a delay of 100ms in between retries

```
    limitedRetryDelay(10, 100, () => agent.TEST("Q.txt")),
    ... etc
```

Now, `winner` is the promise of the race winner

You can either

```
winner.then(t => {
    // t is the winning promise resolved value
});
```

or, if the above code is inside a function tagged `async`, change the second line to

```
let winner = await Promise.race([
... code removed for brevity
]);
// got the winner
```

and winner will be the winning resolved value

Comment: It's ES2017, and the retry function you used is very scary because it never gives up - so a syntax error would be quite confusing

Comment: Parameter 'fn' implicitly has an 'any' type. any suggestions?

Comment: damn, I can never keep up with the ES2015/2016/2017 features (I usually guess rather than research :p ) well ... yes, it is a scary retry :p I do have some generic retries with limited attempts, and delays between them if the OP wants :p

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention that the code is javascript, not typescript - sorry - was just an idea

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that. Surely anyone who knows typescript should have no problem.

Comment: I just tested the code I posted in a typescript playground ... and the code I posted needs absolutely no change to "work" - so not sure why you're worried about it @FarihaAbbasi - there's as much "typescript" in the code I posted as what it replaces in the code you posted